# Does any odd prime number belong to at least one set of a minimum of $3$ prime numbers, that are separated from each other by the same gap?

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, prime-gaps

I have tried searching for the following and I mostly got results dealing with: the rarity of different gaps, twin gaps, cousin gaps...

As a self learner, there is a chance that I didn't know of a better way to search, So if this is a duplicate please close and refer me to it.

I doubt that there is any proof, but I would deeply appreciate any references or any heuristics or any counter example.

The question is quite simple:

Does any odd prime number belong to at least one set of a minimum of $3$ primes numbers, that are separated from each other by the same gap?

*Note: The prime numbers themselves aren't necessarily consecutive in nature.

I am aware that within large prime numbers there are different behaviors, but there are also many more options.

Here are some basic examples:

$3 , 5 , 7$  gap: $2$

$5 , 11  , 17 , 23, 29$ gap: $6$

$7 , 13 , 19$ gap: $6$

$19 , 31 , 43$ gap: $12$

$23 , 41 , 59$  gap: $18$

$23 , 47 , 71$ gap: $40$

$3 , 53 , 103$. gap: $50$

$79 , 109, 139$ gap: $30$

...

Comment: $87=3\times 29$ is not prime, and $2,5,7$ isn't an AP.  See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34197/are-all-primes-in-a-pap-3/34298#34298) for example.

Comment: @user10354138 thank you for noticing. That was embarrassing. I have edited.

Comment: There is still the 87 in 47,67,87,107.

Comment: @user10354138 lol. I have been thinking about it for the last 3 hours, I must be all confused by now. edited again

Comment: @user10354138 your link is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Probably for every prime $p\ge 5$, there is a positive integer $d$, such that $p-d$ and $p+d$ are both prime. However, your conjecture (which is weaker) is probably still out of reach. I currently check the range $5\le p\le 10^8$

Comment: For every prime $p$ with $5\le p\le 10^8$ , there is a positive integer $d\le 3414$ such that $p-d$ and $p+d$ are both prime.

Comment: The query is essentially Goldbach's conjecture, with the stipulation that $p+p$ does not count as a representation of $2p$. Using Peter's variable names, $q,r \in \mathbb P, q=p-d,\ r=p+d \Rightarrow q+r=2p$ which is Goldbach's conjecture for the case $p \in \mathbb P$

Comment: @KeithBackman - While this has a connection to Goldbach's conjecture, it is independent. Proving it would not even add to the known cases for Goldbach's conjecture, as "$2p$ is the sum of two primes" is obvious, and proving no more than Goldbach's conjecture would shed no light on this for the same reason.

Comment: I was remiss in not qualifying my previous comment: This query is essentially Goldbach's conjecture *as it applies to twice primes*...

Comment: I have edited the post to allow only _odd_ prime numbers ($p=2$ obviously doesn't belong to such a set).

Comment: Green-Tao theorem